# Digitalocean kubernetes cluster load balancer doesn't work properly as round robin

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I created a Digitalocean kubernetes cluster and create a service with 4 replicas. the service type is **LoadBalancer**. the load balancer is also created. but I posted my request to the target endpoint by using postman. and I have written the endpoint with the pod **host name**. but every time I get the response from the same pod. if the load is balanced by the load balancer, the requests should go to each and every pods. but is not happening as I expected.
my manifest file like below.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-service-deployment
  labels:
    app: user-service
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-service
          image: myRepo/ms-user-service:1.0.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: proud
            - name: MY_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: user-service
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

please resolve this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to disable the keepalive feature **(service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-backend-keepalive)** when you create the service. under the metadata.annotations you can configure it like the below. [read for more detail.](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/how-to/configure-load-balancers/)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-backend-keepalive: "false"
spec:
  selector:
    app: user-service
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: I got the idea. but the problem is that they have mention that configuration is false by default. anyway after doing that the problem was gone. thanks.